# list of numbers correspond to a line in a file

Tags: python, file, list

I have a list which contains a series of numbers. This list of numbers corresponds to a line in a .dat file. How can I use the list say `[0,1,2,3,4,5,6,9,4]` and then print out the line in the .dat file which each number corresponds to.

Comment: `lines = f.readlines(); lines[i] for i in indices`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'd read the lines into memory, into a list and then index into that list:

```
with open('somefile') as fileobj:
    lines = list(fileobj)

for index in indices:
    print lines[index]
```

Comment: `lines = list(open('somefile'))`. Is there a reason you are promoting this construct instead of using `with`?

Comment: @Abhijit: I was being lazy; it's a simple one-liner that works just fine in CPython.

Answer (score 0):

```
file = [ l for l in open('file.name') ]
for i in list:
   print file[i]
```

Comment: -1.  Don't use names `file` and `list` because they clobber builtins.  Also, I think you mean `for i in file:`.  Finally, files have the `readlines` method so you don't have to use a list comprehension here.

Comment: @thg435:  Ah.  Now I see there is an implicit `list = [0,1,2,3,4,5,6,9,4]` here.  But the other two problems remain, so still -1.

Comment: I take the names implicit, that everybody understands what i do here! Yeah,we could also do fileIn = open('file.name').readlines() instead of a list comprehension!